# Confused by output from Polyval

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, polynomials

I have some data from which I have fitted a 2nd order polynomial using numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit

```
data_fit = poly.polyfit(length_spline_a, temp_spline_b, 2)
```

I am examining changes in length, and have a list of 10% changes in length

```
len_steps = 0.0, -0.012573565669572757, -0.025147131339145513, -0.03772069700871827...
print (len(len_steps)
>>>>11
```

My assumption was that polyval would solve for y for each of the x values in the `len_steps` list

```
y_data = poly.polyval(data_fit, len_steps)
```

However this provides a list with only 3 data points rather than the 11 I expected.

```
print(y_data)
>>>>[-5.34112443e+21 -2.50395581e+28 -6.75169134e+28]
```

Have I mis understood the purpose of polyval or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The output works if I reverse the list order to `y_data = poly.polyval(len_steps, data_fit)`  which is actually clear now I re-read the documents.  I think I was using the np.polyval syntax which expects the coefs first.